# What's wrong with this circulation?

Tags: c++, c

If I remove the `while` and select one condition in the `if, else if, else`, I can get a result. But when I add the `while` circulation into the function solve, an infinite-loop happens. Please figure out where is the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int a, b, c, d;
float fun(float x);
float solve(void);

int main()
{
    printf("Put in the coefficient of the equation:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    scanf("%d", &c);
    scanf("%d", &d);

    float ans = solve();

    printf("A solve for the equation：x=%.3f", ans);

    return 0;
}

float fun(float x)
{
    float value = a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d;

    return value;
}

float solve(void)
{
    float x1 = -100, x2 = 100, x3;
    float diff = fabs(fun(x1) - fun(x2));
    while (diff > 0.001)
    {
        x3 = (x1 * fun(x2) - x2 * fun(x1)) / (fun(x2) - fun(x1));

        if (fun(x3) == 0)
        {
            x1 = x3;
            x2 = x3;
        }
        else if ((fun(x3) * fun(x1)) < 0)
        {
            x2 = x3;
        }
        else
        {
            x1 = x3;
        }

        diff = fabs(fun(x1) - fun(x2));
    }

    return diff;
}
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this as C++?

Comment: Have you already tried printing out the value of `diff` at the end of each loop?

Comment: Equality in floating point numbers is not a good idea - see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: `solve()` returns `diff`, which should be about zero, instead of the solution.

Comment: Why don't _you_ figure out where is the problem!?

Comment: Among other things, your starting points are too far away for a cubic polinomial, so that one of them will be never changed by the loop logic (or at least not before an insane amount of time). It's a flaw of the numeric method you chose to find one of the roots of the function. One possible fix is to choose the midpoint of the interval as next x3 (the bisection method) if the interval x2 - x1 isn't getting smaller enough between successive iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thats c not c++ !!!
If you return diff you everytime get a value smaller than 0.001 as solve.
I think you should return x3.
If you ask `fun(x3) == 0` fun(x3) has to be completly equal zero. You never will reach that in the most cases with floats. Better do it like that:

```
        funx3=fun(x3);

        if (funx3 == 0.0 || funx3>0.0 &&funx3<0.001 || funx3<0.0 && funx3>-0.001 )
        {
            x1 = x3;
            x2 = x3;
        }
```

Also that wont work in all cases. To fix that use doubles in your whole programm. You also will get more decimal places. Im not completly sure if all decimal places will be right. Maybe you hat to cut one eralier.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int a, b, c, d;
double fun(float x);
double solve(void);

int main()
{
    printf("Put in the coefficient of the equation:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    scanf("%d", &c);
    scanf("%d", &d);

    float ans = solve();

    printf("A solve for the equation：x=%.8f", ans);

    return 0;
}

double fun(float x)
{
    double value = a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d;

    return value;
}

double solve(void)
{
    double x1 = -100, x2 =100, x3;
    double diff = fabs(fun(x1) - fun(x2));
    double funx3;
    while (diff > 0.0000001)
    {
        x3 = (x1 * fun(x2) - x2 * fun(x1)) / (fun(x2) - fun(x1));

        funx3=fun(x3);

        if (funx3 == 0.0 || funx3>0.0 &&funx3<0.0000001 || funx3<0.0 && funx3>-0.0000001 )
        {
            x1 = x3;
            x2 = x3;
        }
        else if ((fun(x3) * fun(x1)) < 0.0)
        {
            x2 = x3;
        }
        else
        {
            x1 = x3;
        }

        diff = fabs(fun(x1) - fun(x2));
    }

    return x3;
}
```

Comment: My bad, I changed x1 into diff to print the diff and forgot to change it back. Imma be careful when tagging next time. Sorry.

Comment: I change floats into doubles as you told and it works. But I am still confused that float has 6 significant figures and I chose diff > 0.001 as judging conditions. Why floats are still not precise enough?